# Reading java .properties file from bash

Tags: bash, scripting, properties

I am thinking of using sed for reading .properties file, but was wondering if there is a smarter way to do that from bash script?

Comment: That is a wonderful question :) In this specific I wanted to see if there is a simple way that I am missing(don't know about\too stupid to think of etc.)

Comment: Try to use Gradle to build and deploy, not BASH

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solutions mentioned above will work for the basics.  I don't think they cover multi-line values though.  Here is an awk program that will parse Java properties from stdin and produce shell environment variables to stdout:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="=";
    print "# BEGIN";
    n="";
    v="";
    c=0; # Not a line continuation.
}
/^\#/ { # The line is a comment.  Breaks line continuation.
    c=0;
    next;
}
/\\$/ && (c==0) && (NF>=2) { # Name value pair with a line continuation...
    e=index($0,"=");
    n=substr($0,1,e-1);
    v=substr($0,e+1,length($0) - e - 1);    # Trim off the backslash.
    c=1;                                    # Line continuation mode.
    next;
}
/^[^\\]+\\$/ && (c==1) { # Line continuation.  Accumulate the value.
    v= "" v substr($0,1,length($0)-1);
    next;
}
((c==1) || (NF>=2)) && !/^[^\\]+\\$/ { # End of line continuation, or a single line name/value pair
    if (c==0) {  # Single line name/value pair
        e=index($0,"=");
        n=substr($0,1,e-1);
        v=substr($0,e+1,length($0) - e);
    } else { # Line continuation mode - last line of the value.
        c=0; # Turn off line continuation mode.
        v= "" v $0;
    }
    # Make sure the name is a legal shell variable name
    gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/,"_",n);
    # Remove newlines from the value.
    gsub(/[\n\r]/,"",v);
    print n "=\"" v "\"";
    n = "";
    v = "";
}
END {
    print "# END";
}
```

As you can see, multi-line values make things more complex.  To see the values of the properties in shell, just source in the output:

```
cat myproperties.properties | awk -f readproperties.awk > temp.sh
source temp.sh
```

The variables will have '_' in the place of '.', so the property some.property will be some_property in shell.

If you have ANT properties files that have property interpolation (e.g. '${foo.bar}') then I recommend using Groovy with AntBuilder.

Here is [my wiki page on this very topic](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Reading+Java-style+Properties+Files+with+Shell).

Comment: I have corrected a bug with the script when a multi-line value is the last defined and ends with a blank-line

Comment: Very nice. source <(awk -f readproperties.awk my.properties)

Answer (score 34):

This would probably be the easiest way: grep + cut

```
# Usage: get_property FILE KEY
function get_property
{
    grep "^$2=" "$1" | cut -d'=' -f2
}
```

Comment: This is what I like the most for simple cases. But I would amend with `grep "^$PROP_KEY="`  (including the ^ and = delimiters) because property keys are frequently prefix or postfix of other keys.

Comment: This will fail on any property that contains an equals sign.  A better (more complete, shorter, and even slightly faster) solution would be `sed "/^$2=/!d; s///" "$1"` which has the same logic as the above `grep` but then also deletes the matched portion, leaving just the parameter value to be printed.

Comment: Properties allow whitespace between the property name and the equals sign.  Using the regular expression `^$2 *=` with grep or sed allows spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure this handles multi-line properties.

Comment: Also, this cuts the value if there are `=` (equal) chars in the value. Use `cut -d'=' -f2-`. See the minus char at the end.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a script to solve the problem and put it on my github.

See [properties-parser](https://github.com/shaoshuai0102/properties-parser)

Comment: Awesome!  Copied the script into my project and nicely reads in properties.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to write a simple Java program to do it for you - then run the Java program in your script.  That might seem silly if you're just reading properties from a single properties file.  However, it becomes very useful when you're trying to get a configuration value from something like a Commons Configuration `CompositeConfiguration` backed by properties files.  For a time, we went the route of implementing what we needed in our shell scripts to get the same behavior we were getting from `CompositeConfiguration`.  Then we wisened up and realized we should just let `CompositeConfiguration` do the work for us!  I don't expect this to be a popular answer, but hopefully you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
   ($prop,$val)=split(/[=: ]/, $_, 2);
   # and do stuff for each prop/val
}
```

Not tested, and should be more tolerant of leading/trailing spaces, comments etc., but you get the idea. Whether you use Perl (or another language) over `sed` is really dependent upon what you want to do with the properties once you've parsed them out of the file.

Note that (as highlighted in the comments) Java properties files can have [multiple forms of delimiters](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) (although I've not seen anything used in practice other than colons). Hence the split uses a choice of characters to split upon.

*Ultimately*, you may be better off using the [Config::Properties](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/Config-Properties-25831.shtml) module in Perl, which is built to solve this specific problem.

Comment: That won't necessarily work. The keys and values of the properties file can be delimited by spaces, the = character, or by the : character (there might be other ways too). I believe you can also mix and match which delimiters you use in a single properties file.

Comment: @Thomas - noted. Although in practice I don't recall seeing anything other than colons used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sed to parse -any- .properties file, you may end up with a quite complex solution, since the format allows line breaks, unquoted strings, unicode, etc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

One possible workaround would using java itself to preprocess the .properties file into something bash-friendly, then source it. E.g.:

.properties file:

```
line_a : "ABC"
line_b = Line\
         With\ 
         Breaks!
line_c = I'm unquoted :(
```

would be turned into:

```
line_a="ABC"
line_b=`echo -e "Line\nWith\nBreaks!"`
line_c="I'm unquoted :("
```

Of course, that would yield worse performance, but the implementation would be simpler/clearer.

Comment: `line_b=$'Line\nWith\nBreaks!'`

Comment: Dennis, it didn't work somehow: http://pastebin.com/m503047e8 . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have some [shell scripts](http://zocalo.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zocalo/trunk/devel/bin/DB/startDB?view=markup) that need to look up some .properties and use them as arguments to programs I didn't write.  The heart of the script is a line like this:

```
dbUrlFile=$(grep database.url.file etc/zocalo.conf | sed -e "s/.*: //" -e "s/#.*//")
```

Effectively, that's grep for the key and filter out the stuff before the colon and after any hash.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use "shell", the best tool to parse files and have proper programming control is (g)awk. Use sed only simple substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes just sourced the properties file into the bash script. This will lead to environment variables being set in the script with the names and contents from the file. Maybe that is enough for you, too. If you have to do some "real" parsing, this is not the way to go, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I just run into the same problem today. This is poor man's solution, admittedly more straightforward than clever;)

```
decl=`ruby -ne 'puts chomp.sub(/=(.*)/,%q{="\1";}).gsub(".","_")' my.properties`
eval $decl
```

then, a  property 'my.java.prop' can be accessed as $my_java_prop.

This can be done with sed or whatever, but I finally went with ruby for its 'irb' which was handy for experimenting.
It's quite limited (dots should be replaced only before '=',no comment handling), but could be a starting point.

@Daniel, I tried to source it, but Bash didn't like dots in variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with

```
    PROPERTIES_FILE=project.properties
function source_property {
  local name=$1
  eval "$name=\"$(sed -n '/^'"$name"'=/,/^[A-Z]\+_*[A-Z]*=/p' $PROPERTIES_FILE|sed -e 's/^'"$name"'=//g' -e 's/"/\\"/g'|head -n -1)\""
}

    source_property 'SOME_PROPERTY'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that properly parses quotes and terminates at a space when not given quotes. It is safe: no `eval` is used.

I use this code in my .bashrc and .zshrc for importing variables from shell scripts:

```bash
# Usage: _getvar VARIABLE_NAME [sourcefile...]
# Echos the value that would be assigned to VARIABLE_NAME
_getvar() {
  local VAR="$1"
  shift
  awk -v Q="'" -v QQ='"' -v VAR="$VAR" '
    function loc(text) { return index($0, text) }
    function unquote(d) { $0 = substr($0, eq+2) d; print substr($0, 1, loc(d)-1) }
    { sub(/^[ \t]+/, ""); eq = loc("=") }
    substr($0, 1, eq-1) != VAR { next }  # assignment is not for VAR: skip
    loc("=" QQ) == eq { unquote(QQ); exit }
    loc("="  Q) == eq { unquote( Q); exit }
    { print substr($1, eq + 1); exit }
  ' "$@"
}
```

This saves the desired variable name and then shifts the argument array so the rest can be passed as files to `awk`.

Because it's so hard to call shell variables and refer to quote characters inside `awk`, I'm defining them as `awk` variables on the command line. `Q` is a single quote (apostrophe) character, `QQ` is a double quote, and `VAR` is that first argument we saved earlier.

For further convenience, there are two helper functions. The first returns the location of the given text in the current line, and the second prints the content between the first two quotes in the line using quote character `d` (for "delimiter"). There's a stray `d` concatenated to the first `substr` as a safety against multi-line strings (see "Caveats" below).

While I wrote the code for POSIX shell syntax parsing, that appears to only differ from your format by whether there is white space around the asignment. You can add that functionality to the above code by adding `sub(/[ \t]*=[ \t]*/, "=");` before the `sub(…)` on awk's line 4 (note: line 1 is blank).

The fourth line strips off leading white space and saves the location of the first equals sign. Please verify that your `awk` supports `\t` as tab, this is not guaranteed on ancient UNIX systems.

The `substr` line compares the text before the equals sign to `VAR`. If that doesn't match, the line is assigning a different variable, so we skip it and move to the next line.

Now we know we've got the requested variable assignment, so it's just a matter of unraveling the quotes. We do this by searching for the first location of `="` (line 6) or `='` (line 7) or no quotes (line 8). Each of those lines prints the assigned value.

Caveats: If there is an escaped quote character, we'll return a value truncated to it. Detecting this is a bit nontrivial and I decided not to implement it. There's also a problem of multi-line quotes, which get truncated at the first line break (this is the purpose of the "stray `d`" mentioned above). Most solutions on this page suffer from these issues.

Answer (score 0):

In order to let Java do the tricky parsing, here's a solution using `jrunscript` to print the keys and values in a bash `read`-friendy (key, tab character, value, null character) way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
jrunscript -e '
        p = new java.util.Properties();
        p.load(java.lang.System.in);
        p.forEach(function(k,v) { out.format("%s\t%s\000", k, v); });
    ' < /tmp/test.properties \
| while IFS=$'\t' read -d $'\0' -r key value; do
    key=${key//./_}
    printf -v "$key" %s "$value"
    printf '=> %s = "%s"\n' "$key" "$value"
done
```

I found `printf -v` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973754/2099362) by @david-foerster.

To quote `jrunscript`: Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release