# Read system properties from file specified as java executable argument

Tags: java, file, jboss, properties

By launching java with the -D option you can set System.properties.

Is there a way to specify a properties file as an option for java, which in turn read them as `System.properties`?

E.g.

```
java -Dfile ./alotof.properties
```

I'm building a webapp deployed in JBoss. The jboss xml configuration files accepts system properties as inline config `{my.property}`, which reads from the command line argument but this gets unruly as the number of properties grow.

Comment: you can possibly write a simple class that reads the file and uses System.setProperty; or just change the starting script (bash/bat/etc) and read the properties on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the properties file in bash (in run.sh file), parse properties and create the proper config line for JVM.

Here you can find 2 articles that can help you:

- [Reading Java-style Properties Files with Shell](http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Reading+Java-style+Properties+Files+with+Shell) ([permalink](http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/x/zwAM))
- [Reading java.properties file from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682442/reading-java-properties-file-from-bash)

Comment: As long as the properties are one per line, and have no extraneous whitespace, you can turn a file into command-line arguments simply by saying `JAVA_OPTS="$(sed 's/./"-D&"/' alotof.properties | tr '\n' ' ')"`.

Comment: Did you mean JAVA_OPTS="$(sed 's/./-D&/' alotof.properties | tr '\n' ' ')" ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about giving a direct property file as an argument, but instead you can have startup class which loads at the bootstrap and overrides whatever property you want override from your property file using System.setProperty() method.

Answer (score 1):

Java can't read system properties from a file, but JBoss can - use the [SystemPropertiesService](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/Additional_Services-System_Properties_Management.html), configured through properties-service.xml in the deploy directory.

Comment: Great, I have never saw these bean.