# Convert a string into a variable in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following code

```
let a=1
let b=a

echo $b
```

When i echo b, i want it to refer it's value (which is 'a'), and display the value of a( which is '1')

Can this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indirect variable assignment in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would argue you don't really want to do this.  But instead of convincing you, here's how to do it:

```
$ let a=1
$ b=a
$ echo $b
a
$ eval "echo \$$b"
1
```

note that you can't use "let" for the second assignment since you want to access the right-hand-side as a string later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `let b=$a`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sharet. In my case that is not the scenario. I just have a string, which may be 'a1', 'a2' or 'a3'. I get this particular string from sql server. I have predefined variables a1, a2 and a3. I just have to access the corresponding variable for the string.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is bash, then what you wrote actually sets `b` to "1" (not "a") because the `$` is optional in arithmetic expressions (which you force with the use of `let`).

Without using `let`, this is the syntax you're looking for (assuming bash): `a=1; b=a; echo $b ${!b}` which outputs `a 1`