# How to use eval to read variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is the scenario:
suppose I set positional variables:

```
set 1 2 3 4
eval "args_$1=something"
```

how do I read args_1,args_2,args_3... variables
I tried

```
echo $args_$1
```

and this also not working

```
eval "\$$(echo arg_$1)"
```

How do I get value of $arg_1, to display on terminal or pass to a function, etc.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: Using eval is not recommended but, you can try: set 1 2 3 4; eval arg_$1=koba; eval echo $\`echo arg_$1\`

Comment: The answer I most strongly endorse from the linked question, by the way, is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973754/14122 -- which, in the case given here, would mean something like `printf -v "$args_$1" %s value`

Comment: ...but really, read BashFAQ #6 for a more complete answer / set of approaches than what's available here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ set 1 2 3 4; eval arg_$1=koba; eval echo $`echo arg_$1`
koba
```

PS: Using eval is not recommended.

Comment: Please can you share the other ways of doing it

Answer (score 2):

Without eval:

```
$ set 1 2 3 4
$ var="args_$1"
$ declare "$var=foo"
$ echo "$var"
args_1
$ echo "${!var}"
foo
```

This uses an [indirect variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).