# Modify the value of ${!i}

Tags: bash, variables

All is in the title, this formula permit to show the value of {!i} but not to modify it, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indirect variable assignment in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash)

Comment: ⚠️ **Please stop posting (and upvoting) answers!** All three answers posted here are duplicates of answers to [this seven year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash). If you have a genuinely new answer, post it there, not here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf -v`.

```
$ x=foo
$ foo=5
$ printf -v "$x" '%d' 9
$ echo "$foo"
9
```

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973754/6770384.

Answer (score -1):

Use declare:

```
$ foo=bar
$ declare $foo=hello
$ echo $bar
hello
```

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460242/6770384.

Comment: And that makes the answer bad and less helpful? With this attitude, less answers will be posted, because they may be duplicates of something old. Anyway, I don't change my behavior.

Comment: This answer got posted *after* the hint *"possible duplicate of"* was there. Also I think each user should research whether a question is an *exact* duplicate before answering - especially for basic questions like this.

Answer (score -2):

Mostly used syntax are as others answer.
A less interesting answer would be to use `read`:

```
foo=5
i="foo"
echo "${!i}"
# yields "5"

read -r "$i" <<< 10
echo "${!i}"
# yields "10"
```

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51948654/6770384.