# Indirect lvalue reference in bash

Tags: bash, variables, indirection

I know that bash supports indirect variable references using the `!` operator:

```
$ ABC=123
$ DEF=ABC
$ echo ${!DEF}
123
```

and that's nice. But - it doesn't seem work when I want to *set the value* of a variable, whose name I get from another variable:

```
$ ABC=123
$ DEF=ABC
$ !DEF=1234
-bash: !DEF=1234: event not found
$ ${!DEF}=1234
-bash: 123=1234: command not found
```

Other than by using `eval` - how can I set the value of a variable whose name is the value of another variable?

Comment: You can create a `nameref`. See [man 1 bash - nameref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) I think that was a bash 4.x addition.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Is this supported with any bash version, or just newer ones?

Comment: It will work with the newer 4.x on. The nameref was added to get around limitations in the indirect reference. It's still not perfect. But it will work here, e.g. `abc=123; declare -n ref=abc; ref=1234; echo $abc` gives you `1234`

Comment: Since bash 4.0 was release in 2009 -- that should cover any current OS -- unless it is really really old.

Comment: `declare -n `was introduced with version 4.3. [Source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061)

Comment: That moves things up 5-years to 2014. That is in still running old server territory (it would be embarrassing to note, I just retired a box put in service in 2002 last year -- an old Abit KT7-raid with Tbird processor - caps finally gave out `:)`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Indirect variable assignment in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash). See [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460242/10248678).

Comment: The problem with [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460242/10248678) with the question above is `123` is not a valid identifier for the indirect variable when using `declare` or `typeset` alone. (can't have an identifier begin with a number). That is what `nameref` avoids.

Comment: @David Didn't understand what you mean but the answer also includes a solution using namerefs.

Comment: Yes, but the declare and typeset would leave the indirect reference in the example starting with a number which would make it an invalid variable name. It appears there is just an extra `'$'` included. For example if `val=123` (as in this question) then `typeset $var=$val` results in the indirect reference in `var` being `$123`.