# Updating variables by reference in bash script?

Tags: bash, envsubst

Is it possible to use a variable by reference in bash scripting [in the way it is done in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/)?

Lets say I have a script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

A="say"
B=$A
echo "B is $B"
A="say it"
echo "B is $B" # This does not get the new value of A but is it possible to using some trick?
```

You see in above script `echo "B is $B` outputs `B is say` even if the value of `A` has changed from `say` to `say it`. I know that reassignment like `B=$A` will solve it. But I want to know if it is possible that `B` holds a reference to `A` so that `B` updates it's value as soon as `A` updates. And this happens without reassignment that is `B=$A`. Is this possible?

I read about `envsubst` from [Lazy Evaluation in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900707/lazy-evaluation-in-bash). Is following the way to do it?

```
A="say"
B=$A
echo "B is $B"
envsubst A="say it"
echo "B is $B"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277932/bash-indirect-variable-referencing https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421110/reference-bash-variable-from-a-variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61983306/indirect-lvalue-reference-in-bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-another-variables-name-in-bash etc.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer Yes. It's better now. Bash doesn't have references but you could do what KamilCuk suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Updating variables by reference in bash script?

And similar to C++, once you assign the *value* of a variable, there is no way to track where from the value came from. In shell all variables store strings. You can store variable name as a string inside another variable, which acts as the reference. You can use:

Bash indirect expansion:

```
A="say"
B=A
echo "B is ${!B}"
A="say it"
echo "B is ${!B}"
```

Bash namereferences:

```
A="say"
declare -n B=A
echo "B is $B"
A="say it"
echo "B is $B"
```

Evil `eval`:

```
A="say"
B=A
eval "echo \"B is \$$B\""
A="say it"
eval "echo \"B is \$$B\""
```

> Is this possible?

Yes - store the name of the variable in `B`, instead of the value.

> envsubst from Lazy Evaluation in Bash. Is following the way to do it?

No, `envsubst` does something different.