# Increment a variable name in ksh

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, ksh

I have several variables that have a value and I am trying to increment the variable names using a for loop. Example

```
#!/bin/ksh
$var1="Hi" $var2="world" 
while ..... 
(($i++)) 
echo $var$i
```

And I have also tried

```
${var[i]}
```

and different variants but nothing worked.
The result I expect is
Hi
world

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `while .....`? Where is `$i` coming from? It is not set anywhere

Comment: Which shell, ksh or Bash?

Comment: For Bash: [Indirect variable assignment in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash)

Comment: 1. while : do ..... done
2. The script is in ksh

Comment: it looks like you want to use an array

Comment: Without using arrays there is no possible way?