# Read a file line by line and add variable to the end of each line

Tags: bash

I have a set of variables populated eg

```
var1="test"
var2="test2"
```

I have a .env file as follows

```
var1
var2
var3=test3
```

I need to read the .env file and append the value of each variable to the relevant line unless the line already has a value.
So what I would end up with in my .env is

```
var1=test
var2=test2
var3=test3
```

what I have so far is:

```
function populate_envs {
      while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        if [[ $line =~ "=" ]]; then
          printf '%s\n' "$line"
        else
          printf '%s=$${%s}\n' "$line" "$line"
        fi
      done <$1
    }
```

I'm currently printing the values to console so as not to change my file at the moment.

the problem is $${%s} is not working neither is $%s. I don't know how to get it to transpose the actual variable value.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) and [Indirect variable assignment in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9938649/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just not how Bash works. The correct line would be:

```
printf '%s=%s\n' "$line" "${!line}"
```

Explanation: Bash expands variables *before* running the command, so you cannot use whatever printf expands `%s` to as the variable name. Also, variables are not allowed at all inside single quotes. But most importantly, Bash doesn't support indirection through `$${var}`. Lucky for you, Bash *does* support indirection in two other ways. If you have a variable `a=1` and you want to reference it indirectly, you can either do:

1. `b=a; echo ${!b}`. The exclamation mark tells Bash to use the value of `b` as the name of the variable to actually use
2. `declare -n b=a; echo $b`. The `-n` option tells Bash to declare `b` as a reference to `a`, so whenever `b` is referenced, the value of `a` is used

Answer (score 1):

One idea using `bash` namerefs:

```
populate_envs() {
    while read -r line
    do
        [ -z "${line}" ] && continue                      # skip blank/empty lines
        IFS='=' read -r attrib value <<< "${line}"        # split line on "=" delimiter
        declare -n _var="${attrib}"                       # define nameref variable
        echo "${attrib}=${value:-${_var}}"                # print new line; if $value is empty then substitute the current value of the nameref variable
    done < "$1"
}
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
var1="test"
var2="test2"

populate_envs .env
```

This generates:

```
var1=test
var2=test2
var3=test3
```

Comment: First time I have seen the use of a `nameref` variable.  Thanks for the detail in the comment.

Comment: Same here. Fairly interesting. I used `eval` a lot to do similar job. Apparently `nameref` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `eval`

```
while read -r line; do
    eval echo "$line"
done < <(sed -E 's/^[^=]+$/&=$&/' .env)
```

The .env file is first processed by `sed`. Essentially, if a variable has nothing assigned, it will be turned into `var=$var` format, e.g.

```
var1=$var1
var2=$var2
var3=test3
```

Then eval each line to generate final result, e.g.

```
var1=test
var2=test2
var3=test3
```