# How to make indirect assignment work without eval

Tags: bash

If I set

```
command="ls -1"
```

I can execute the indirect command via a simple expansion

```
$command
```

However, If I set

```
assignment="a=1"
```

then

```
$assignment
```

works, but bash interprets the result as a command and not as an assignment and gives an error

```
bash: a=1: command not found
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Note. I can use eval to achieve the assignment but I wanted to avoid using eval

```
eval $assignment
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indirect variable assignment in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash)

Comment: Yes, for assignments specifically, `declare` is the answer. For arbitrary snippets of code, `eval` is required (even if not desired).

Comment: `assignment="eval a=1"`? And see [Disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eval/info).

Comment: `declare $assignment` works as expected @glenn jackman

Comment: Why would you not do `assignment() { a=1; }; assignment`? [Variables hold data. Functions hold code](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Any time you think you want to assign something to a variable name only known at run time is a big clue you should be using an associative array instead.

Comment: You should not store a command in a string in bash. Even in POSIX sh you should avoid it (use `$@` instead if you can).

Comment: This should work as well : `assignment='declare a=1'`

Comment: @DeltaGeorge, it will _not_ work with the variable unquoted if there is any whitespace. Try `x='a="Hello world"'` and then with `declare "$x"` and `declare $x` -- **always** quote your variables unless you know exactly when not to.

Comment: @Philippe, how so? what if you're given `assignment='declare a="hello world"'`

Comment: There is a less elegant way to make it work:
`assignment='a="hello world"'`
`. <(echo $assignment)`

Comment: All of these three options work
`assignment='a="hello world"'`
`declare "$assignment"`
`eval $assignment`
`. <(echo $assignment)`